# Laravel 5.3 relationship issue

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

```
class Game extends Model
{
public function regions() {
    return $this->hasMany('Region');
}
public function servers() {
    return $this->hasMany('Server');
}
}

class Region extends Model
{
public function servers() {

    return $this->belongsToMany('Server');
}
}

class Server extends Model
{
public function regions() {
    return $this->hasMany('Region');
}
}
```

Every game has a server and every server has a region.
I'm trying to get all the games, its server and its region:game=Game::with('regions', 'regions.servers')->find($id);

I get an error, that: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'region_server' doesn't exist (SQL: select `servers`.*, `region_server`.`region_id` as `pivot_region_id`, `region_server`.`server_id` as `pivot_server_id` from `servers` inner join `region_server` on `servers`.`id` = `region_server`.`server_id` where `region_server`.`region_id` in (4, 5)

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: `Every game has a server and every server has a region.` Well in your code, you're saying every game has many servers and every server has many regions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your relationships seems to be broken, you should do it like this:

```
class Game extends Model
{
    public function regions() {
        return $this->hasMany('Region');
    }
    public function servers() {
        return $this->hasMany('Server');
    }
}

class Region extends Model
{
    public function servers() {
      return $this->hasMany('Server');
    }
}

class Server extends Model
{
    public function region() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Region');
    }
}
```

According to the above relationships,

- Every Game has many Servers.
- Every Server belongs to a Region
- Every Region has many Servers

Hope this helps

Comment: @user3844579 - If you find this answer correct, then mark this as accepted answer as it motivates me to answer more questions like this :D , and help others to get appropriate answers quickly

Comment: will do it in 6 minutes, haha (stackoverflow limit)